# If I have 2 tables that must have many-to-many relationship to a tags table, do I need 2 intermediate tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have 3 tables - `images`, `videos` and `tags`. Currently I have only one intermediate table called `tag_image` which stores the relation between images and tags. Do I need a second `tag_video` intermediate table for the relationships between my videos and tags, or could I alter the `tag_image` table and make it useable by both?

If I have 2 intermediate tables, would I be able to create a view and display all images AND videos that have a certain tag?

Comment: [Laravel Docs - 5.6 - Eloquent - Relationships - Many to Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Is taggable_type images or videos in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a many to many relationship you will have to have to a separate table to keep the tag and video relationship.

Otherwise you will be having repetitive data in the `tag_image` table.

Comment: Ok so I should create a second intermediate table? Using https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations is not a good idea?

Comment: @Bobimaru Yes. That way you won't have repetetive data. Just imagine one `tag` has multiple `videos`. Then you will have to enter all the `videos` for all the corresponding tag entries. Whereas if you have a separate table you will have only one entry. Sorry for the late reply.